# Contract deployment won't confirm in mist wallet

Tags: contract-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a contract on the mainnet, and I'm using Solidity 0.4.24

I can only deploy the contract as byte code because I can't figure out how to upgrade the solidity compiler in mist (the question is not about that).

Deploying the contract as byte code works fine on Ropsten. However, on the mainnet I tried at least 20 times and I always get 0 confirmations. I even increased the FEE slider to the maximum.

My question:

- Does the mainnet not yet accept this version of solidity?
- Do I have to increase the fee even more?
- Is it because I'm deploying it as byte code directly?

Comment: Are you able to publish any transactions to mainnet via Mist?  Try sending a few Wei to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this solved my problem:

- Quit MIST
- Stop geth
- Start geth with `--cache=1024`
- Start MIST

Now it works. Maybe it just needed a restart, maybe I got lucky or maybe it was the cache parameter.